# How to display edited svg image inside paintevent function in Qt

Tags: qt

displayAuxChartBySVG() function is executed in paintevent. Inside the displayAuxChartBySVG() function, there is a code that modifies the properties of the svg file, and I am trying to display the modified svg file image, but the original svg image is displayed instead of the modified svg image. How can I display the modified svg image?

```
void MainWindow::displayAuxChartBySVG(Uart* protocol){
    qDebug() << "displayAuxChartBySVG func";
    QImage image;
    QPainter chartPainter;
    chartPainter.begin(this);


    int chartKey = protocol->chartPage;
    char svgFilePath[128];

    sprintf(svgFilePath, "%s/%d.svg", AUX_CHART_IMAGE_SVG_FILE_PATH, chartKey - (e_NORMAL_CHART_COUNT + 1));

    qDebug() << "svgFilePath : " << svgFilePath;

    QFile file(svgFilePath);

    if(file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text) == true){
        qDebug() << "file open success";
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "file open fail";
    }

    QDomDocument doc("mydocument");
    if(!doc.setContent(&file)){
        qDebug() << "return";
        file.close();
        return;
    }

    QDomElement docElem = doc.documentElement();
    QDomNode n = docElem.firstChild();

    //int childNodeCnt = docElem.childNodes().count();
    //qDebug() << "childNodeCnt : " << childNodeCnt;


    while(!n.isNull()){
        QDomElement e = n.toElement();
        //qDebug() << "e.tagName() : " << e.tagName();
        if(!e.isNull()){
            if((e.tagName() == "circle") && ((e.attribute("id") == "circle00") || (e.attribute("id") == "circle01"))){
                //e.setAttribute("fill", "#00BFFF");
                e.setAttribute("stroke", "#00BFFF");
                e.setAttribute("stroke-width", "20px");
                qDebug() << "success setAttribute";
            }
        }
        n = n.nextSibling();
    }

    QSvgWidget* svgWidget = new QSvgWidget;

    svgWidget->load(doc.toByteArray());
    //setCentralWidget(svgWidget);

    image.load(svgFilePath);
    chartPainter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    chartPainter.drawImage(0, 0, image);
}
```

Comment: On which widget do you want to show it? svgWidget or MainWindow? Currently you draw on MainWindow, but not as part of a paint event and you create a QSvgWidget which is not part of the MainWindow. What ist the base class of MainWindow?

Comment: try save edited svg file before the call to ```image.load(svgFilePath);```?

Comment: @BenjaminBuch Thank u for your help. I want to put a svg image in my MainWindow. But I don't know how.

Comment: @kenash0625 you're right. But I don't know how to save the edited svg file.

Comment: @BenjaminBuch The base class is QMainWindow. class MainWindow : public QMainWindow

Comment: @areyouwho of you want to paint on MainWindow, it must not have any children widgets. Is that the case? If not, you should create a child widget and paint on that instead.